# python pyqt: How to call multiple modules using for loop?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I want to call multiple modules using for loop in paintEvent(), like

```
 def fun1(self,paint,a,b):
     do something ...
 def fun2(self,paint,a,b):
     do something ...
 def fun3(self,paint,a,b):
     do something .... 

 def paintEvent(self,event=None):
     for i in range (1,3):
        self.fun[i](self,paint,a,b)
```

basically my fun1, fun2 and fun3 are drawing some widgets and are almost same. Please help me how to call these functions using for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
def fun1(self,paint,a,b):
    do something ...
def fun2(self,paint,a,b):
    do something ...
def fun3(self,paint,a,b):
    do something .... 

self.fun = [self.fun1,self.fun2,self.fun3]

def paintEvent(self,event=None):
    for i in range (1,3):
       self.fun[i](self,paint,a,b)
```

If fun1, fun2, and fun3 are almost the same thing as you have said, you should consider combining them into one function that you can call with an additional argument.

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like:

```
def fun1(self, paint, a, b):
    pass

def fun2(self, paint, a, b):
    pass

def fun3(self,paint, a, b):
    do something .... 


def paintEvent(self, event=None):
    functions = [self.fun1, self.fun2, self.fun3]
    for func in functions:
        func(paint, a, b)
```

or if you're sure about the function names, like they have a similar naming pattern, even this could work:

```
def paintEvent(self, event=None):
    for attr_name in dir(self):
        if attr_name.startswith('fun'):
            func = getattr(self, attr_name)
            func(paint, a, b)
```

Comment: thanks for your solutions, just I want to ask how to write for loop for assigning QColor function like....... for i in range (3): self.color[i]=QColor(Qt.blue), because I do not want to write self.color1=QColor(Qt.blue), self.color2=QColor(Qt.blue), self.color3=QColor(Qt.blue)

Comment: could you store those colors in a dict? self.colors = dict() for i in range(3): self.colors[i] = QColor(Qt.blue)